# How to send muti-part form data with image and file, from ios to php server?

Tags: php, ios, forms, post, file-upload

I tried to send form data (with image and file uploads) from ios to php server, failed in all attempts. After debugging, I found that:

- When I send only form data and image, it works fine. But when I include file upload (in this case, an mp3 file), it failed. The form data and the image file are not even delivered to the php side.
- If I do not include the mp3 file, the server side will get the form data and image file.
- If I send only the mp3 file, it does not work.

This is my ios code:

```
//beginning data
NSDictionary *dictSong;
NSArray *arrImages; // Array of UIImage
NSArray *arrFiles; // Array of local file names to be sent to the server

// Build the request body
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:link]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

// add the text form fields
if([dictData count] > 0) {
    for (id key in dictData) {
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", key] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:[dictData valueForKey:key]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }
}
// add the image form fields
if ([arrImages count] > 0) {
    for(id key in arrImages) {
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: attachment; name=\"picture\"; filename=\"image.png\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(key, 1.0)]];
        //[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:key]];
        [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }
}
// add the file form fields
if ([arrFiles count] != 0) {
    for(id key in arrFiles) {
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *docsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *dataPath = docsDir;
        if(folder)
            dataPath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@",folder]];
        NSString *fullPath = [dataPath stringByAppendingFormat:@"/%@", key];
        NSLog(@"fullPath: %@", fullPath); // file path has also been checked

        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: attachment; name=\"file\"; filename=\"file.mp3\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        //[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; // I tried this line and the following line, but still failed
        [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: audio/mp3\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fullPath]];
        [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }
}

// close the form
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// set request body
[request setHTTPBody:body];
```

And then I send the request through NSURLSESSION:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
self.session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration];

NSURLSessionDataTask *uploadTask = [self.session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) { //Treat the response
}];
```

At the server side, I check:

```
echo $_POST["username"];
echo $_POST["password"];
```

or

```
$_FILES["picture"]["size"]
```

They are nil if I include arrFiles to the form submit, but correct data otherwise. What did I do wrong?

Comment: It seems like I cannot fire data task or upload task with form data and big files together. So I chose a way around by sending form data and image file first (using data task), and then, based on the returned data, send the song file (using upload task). It's not very elegant, but at least it worked, after a headache of about 2 weeks.

Answer (score 0):

I did not succeed in sending form data alongside file upload. So the way around was that:

1. I post a form data alongside image file in a data task to the server;
2. After inserting the data in the database, I instruct the server to return the id of the newly inserted item back to the app;
3. I upload the song file through upload task to the server, using the id received in point 2 above.

Cheers! For those who may have a better solution, please share. Thanks.